# Find target and run make in subdirectory

Tags: makefile

Suppose i have the following directory structure:

```
root
|--Makefile
|--dir1
|   |--Makefile
|   |--tmp1.c
|--dir2
    |--Makefile
    |--tmp2.c
```

dir1/Makefile contains target tmp1 for compiling tmp1.c:

```
tmp1:tmp1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) %< -o %@
```

In a same way dir2/Makefile contains a target tmp2 for compiling tmp2.c

What i want is to simply run `make tmp1` or `make tmp2` from root directory without explicitly defining this targets in root/Makefile.

For recursive make i use the following:

```
SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2
$(SUBDIRS): 
      $(MAKE) -C $@
```

I just need some way to pass specified target to this recursive make call so it can finds Makefile which contains a target and run it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which makefile(s) can you modify?

Comment: I assume you mean `SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2` not `SUBDIRS = tmp1 tmp2`.  How do you intend make to know which of the subdirs it should invoke when you say `make tmp1`, if you're not defining a target `tmp1` in the root makefile?

Comment: I can modify all makfiles.

Comment: Yes, i mean `SUBDIRS = dir1 dir2` , thanks. If i define tmp1 target in root/Makefile like this: `tmp1: MAKE = make tmp1` `tmp1: $(SUBDIRS)` it finds the right directory and execute makefile there, but i want it to work without defining all targets in root/Makefile, by using some pattern rule or something like that.